# Memory Leak with Asynchronous WCF service call

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, memory-leaks

I have a WCF windows service, Service1, calling another WCF windows service, Service2, locate on another machine.  The memory consumed by Service1 grows until I am forced to restart the service. I have run a profiler, and it appears that the calls are not being disposed of properly.

[image: Profiler image]

I believe I am calling Service2 properly from Service1 and disposing correctly.

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service1 : IService, IDisposable
{
    private static bool CallService2()
    {
        Record record = //Create a Record
        Service2Client client = new Service2Client();
        try
        {
            client.BeginAddRecord(record, Service2Callback, client);
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                client.Abort();

            }
        }
    }    
    public static void Service2Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        bool closed = false;
        try
        {
            ((Service2Client)ar.AsyncState).EndAddRecord(ar);
            ((Service2Client)ar.AsyncState).Close();
            closed = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //error logging
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (!closed)
                {
                    ((Service2Client)ar.AsyncState).Abort();
                }
            }catch(Exception){
                //ErrorLogging
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Close examination of the profiler results show that the "Record" object I am passing to Service2 is never being released from memory.

Thank you,
AFrieze

Comment: Now try  your code with without using *async* codes.

Comment: Requirement for this project is that Service1 not be delayed by Service2.  If the call to Service 2 fails or something goes wrong, that is fine for Service1 as the call was asynchronous.  I should also mention that I have not been able to reproduce this memory leak locally, only on production environment.

Comment: Why are you using single instance? And how are you hosting? IIS/SelfHost/other

Comment: Their are some shared resources that single instance mode made easier to manage. Could this be related?

Comment: Both services are installed as windows services.

Comment: Does CPU also spike up or only memory?

Comment: @AFrieze I don't understand your requirement. You want to use the result of service2 in service1 without waiting the result?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Only Memory

Comment: Service1 does not care about result returned from Service2.  Service1 should not even care if Service2 crashes.  All Service1 should do is call service2 in an asynchronous manor and ensure that the connections are cleaned up appropriately.

Comment: Does `Record` implement `IDisposable`? And `Service2Client`?

Comment: Record does not.  Should it?  I don't believe there are any unmanaged items within.  Only strings, enums, bools,DateTimes, and lists which contain objects or tuples with strings,enums, DateTimes, and bools.  Service2 was autogenerated when I added a service reference to the project.

Comment: I wondered if you need to call `Dispose` on `Record`, but you don't. But if `Service2Client` implements `IDisposable` then you need to call `Dispose` on it. I can't say this will fix the leak though. Maybe you could post the code for `BeginAddRecord`?

Comment: I'll take a look at calling dispose on the Service2Client, thanks for the suggestion.  The code for BeginAddRecord is also autogenerated by the .net framework.